# Constraint for key or field dotted off of key

Tags: typescript

TypeScript allows you to constrain an argument to be a key of some type.

```
function foo<T>(obj: T, property: keyof T){ ... }

foo('hello world', 'length'); //Valid
foo('hello world', 'bar');    //Not Valid
```

I know the generic constraints in TypeScript have become very powerful; is there a way to constrain the argument to be not just a key of T, but also any valid expression dotted off a key of T?

So for example:

```
function foo<T>(obj: T, property: MythicalConstraintHere){ ... }

foo({dog: { cat: 'hello world' } }, 'dog');     //Valid
foo({dog: { cat: 'hello world' } }, 'bar');     //Not Valid
foo({dog: { cat: 'hello world' } }, 'dog.cat'); //Valid
```

The use-case here is to be able to have a constraint that works for binding expressions.

Answer (score 0):

May not be exactly what you're looking for, but here's what you can do:

```
function foo<T>(obj: T, property1: keyof T, property2?: keyof T[keyof T]) { 
  // ...
}

foo({dog: { cat: 'hello world' } }, 'dog');           // Valid
foo({dog: { cat: 'hello world' } }, 'dog', 'cat');    // Valid
foo({dog: { cat: 'hello world' } }, 'cat');           // Not Valid
foo({dog: { cat: 'hello world' } }, 'dog', 'pig');    // Not Valid
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zae1v8) (the editor itself is enough to see what's valid and what's not)